# PHP array_walk doesn't work properly

Tags: php, arrays

I've read a lot of posts related to array_walk but I can't fully understand why my code doesn't work. Here is my example.

The `$new_array` is empty when I do the `var_dump`, If I write `var_dump` on every iteration it shows some value, meaning that is treating the `$new_array` as a new variable on every iteration, I don't know why this is.. Does anyone know what is the error occurred in this code ?

```
$exploded = explode(",", $moveArray[0]);

print_r($exploded);

$new_array = array();
array_walk($exploded,'walk', $new_array);

function walk($val, $key, &$new_array){
    $att = explode('=',$val);
    $new_array[$att[0]] = $att[1];

}

var_dump($new_array);
```

Comment: A side note, you can use [anonymous function with `use()` language structure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) if you're using PHP >= 5.3

Comment: i tried, it didnt work

Comment: It should work with `use`: http://3v4l.org/kRYD7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into your code I've found that your issue is to parse something like: `a=b,c=d,e=f`. Actually, since your question is about using [`array_walk()`](https://www.php.net/array_walk), there's correct usage:

```
$string = 'foo=bar,baz=bee,feo=fee';

$result = [];
array_walk(explode(',', $string), function($chunk) use (&$result)
{
   $chunk = explode('=', $chunk);
   $result[$chunk[0]]=$chunk[1];
});
```

-i.e. to use [anonymous function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), which affects context variable `$result` via accepting it by reference.

But your case, in particular, even doesn't require [`array_walk()`](https://www.php.net/array_walk):

```
$string = 'foo=bar,baz=bee,feo=fee';

preg_match_all('/(.*?)\=(.*?)(,|$)/', $string, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

-or even:

```
//will not work properly if values/names contain '&' 
$string = 'foo=bar,baz=bee,feo=fee';
parse_str(str_replace(',', '&', $string), $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this.

```
$new_array = array();
array_walk($exploded,'walk');

function walk($val, $key){
    global $new_array;
    $att = explode('=',$val);
    $new_array[$att[0]] = $att[1];

}
```

Comment: `global`? are you joking?